# Правильный RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сейчас .htaccess такой

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# MultiViews interfers with proper rewriting
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
# Uncomment and properly set the RewriteBase if the rewrite rules are not working properly
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule . rewrite.php [L]
```

Все нормально работает перенаправляет все страницы на rewrite.php кроме:

1. Главной страницы (site.ru, site.ru/index.php)
2. И почему-то админки (site.ru/?mod=admin, site.ru/index.php?mod=admin)

Ну вот админка как раз таки и не нужна для перенаправления. Нужно только включить главную страницу.

Пытался сам сделать.

После `#RewriteBase /`

добавил `RewriteRule ^index.php$ rewrite.php [L]`

Главная страница начала перенаправляться на rewrite.php, но также начала и перенаправляться ссылка в админку `(site.ru/?mod=admin, site.ru/index.php?mod=admin)`. А админка как известно не нужна. Прошу помощи в этом вопросе....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !mod=admin
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ rewrite.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . rewrite.php [L]
```

Или так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     !mod=admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      =/index.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . rewrite.php [L]
```